# Orbeon: How to display dynamic dropdown values from file system resource

Tags: forms, dynamic, drop-down-menu, dropdown, orbeon

I am new to Orbeon and trying to implement a dynamic dropdown where the values are populated from a lookup xml on file system.

So here's the requirement:
The first dropdown (Animal) will have 2 values: Cat and Dog. Based on the selection, the second dropdown (Breeds) will display the list of breeds.

The 2 xml files containing the breeds are registered as resources and look like this:

CAT: \forms\quote\lookup\catbreeds.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<breeds>
    <item>
        <value>C1</value>
        <label>Domestic Long Hair</label>
    </item>
    <item>
        <value>C2</value>
        <label>Domestic Medium Hair</label>
    </item>
    <item>
        <value>C3</value>
        <label>Domestic Short Hair</label>
    </item>
    <item>
        <value>C4</value>
        <label>Mixed Breed</label>
    </item>
    <item>
        <value>C5</value>
        <label>Tabby</label>
    </item>
    <item>
        <value>C6</value>
        <label>Abyssinian</label>
    </item>
    <item>
        <value>C7</value>
        <label>American Bobtail</label>
    </item>
</breeds>
```

DOG: \forms\quote\lookup\dogbreeds.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<breeds>
    <item>
        <value>D1</value>
        <label>Cavapoo</label>
    </item>
    <item>
        <value>D2</value>
        <label>Cockapoo</label>
    </item>
    <item>
        <value>D3</value>
        <label>Crossbreed</label>
    </item>
    <item>
        <value>D4</value>
        <label>Goldendoodle</label>
    </item>
    <item>
        <value>D5</value>
        <label>Labradoodle</label>
    </item>
    <item>
        <value>D6</value>
        <label>Maltipoo</label>
    </item>
    <item>
        <value>D7</value>
        <label>Mi Ki</label>
    </item>
</breeds>
```

The form.xml looks like this:

Model:

```
<xf:instance id="fr-form-instance" xxf:exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
<form>
    <section-1>
        <animal/>
        <breed/>
    </section-1>
</form>
</xf:instance>
<xf:instance id="pets"
    xmlns="">
    <root>
        <item name="Cat" value="cat"/>
        <item name="Dog" value="dog"/>
    </root>
</xf:instance>
```

Body:

```
<xh:body>
<fr:view>
    <fr:body
        xmlns:oxf="http://www.orbeon.com/oxf/processors"
        xmlns:p="http://www.orbeon.com/oxf/pipeline"
        xmlns:xbl="http://www.w3.org/ns/xbl">
        <fr:section id="section-1-control" class="no-header-section" bind="section-1-bind">
            <fr:grid>
                <xh:tr>
                    <xh:td>
                        <fr:dropdown-select1 id="animal-control" ref="animal" bind="breed-bind">
                            <xf:label ref="$form-resources/animal/label"/>
                            <xf:itemset ref="instance('pets')/item">
                                <xf:label ref="@name"/>
                                <xf:value ref="@value"/>
                            </xf:itemset>
                        </fr:dropdown-select1>
                    </xh:td>
                </xh:tr>
                <xh:tr>
                    <xh:td>
                        <fr:dropdown-select1 id="breed-control" bind="breed-bind">
                            <xf:label ref="$form-resources/breed/label"/>
                            <xf:itemset
                                        ref="doc('oxf:/forms/quote/lookup/catbreeds.xml')/breeds/item">
                                <xf:label ref="label"/>
                                <xf:value ref="value"/>
                            </xf:itemset>
                        </fr:dropdown-select1>
                    </xh:td>
                </xh:tr>
            </fr:grid>
        </fr:section>
    </fr:body>
</fr:view>
</xh:body>
```

Now, the "ref" attribute in ref="doc('oxf:/forms/quote/lookup/**catbreeds**.xml')/breeds/item"> is where the problem is. I am able to load the individual lists (in this case it loads Cat breeds) but I am not able to find a way to make it conditional.

I found that I cannot use XPath for ref (like this:oxf:/forms/quote/lookup/{**animal**}breeds.xml) to make the value dynamic.

I have been trying a lot of things but nothing is working out. It will be a great help if someone can give me a direction.
I'm on Orbeon 4.8

Answer (score 0):

Since the value of `ref` is XPath, you can build the URL you pass to `doc()` dynamically, by doing something along these lines:

```
doc(concat(
    'oxf:/forms/quote/lookup/',
    instance('fr-form-instance')/section-1/animal,
    'breeds.xml'
))/breeds/item
```

Comment: Hi Alex. Thank you so much for your response. It is concatenating the string but now I have another issue. I am not able to setup the default value for animal. I tried: 
`<xf:bind id="animal-bind" ref="animal" name="animal" xxf:default="Cat"/>`
But it doesnt work. I saw an open issue related to this in github  https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/3028
What's the best way to do it? 
Thanks and regards

Comment: Hi Vivek, indeed `xxf:default` won't do it for a dynamic dropdown. But if the default is static, you could instead put the value in the instance by editing the source of the form. You'll let me know if this helps.